# Trying to map a room with Arduino controlled bot

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi, hc-sr04

[image]

What you see above is a map of my room. The boxes in black are obstacles and the box in red is my bot.

Now I want my bot to go around the room, avoiding all obstacles, but at the same time, covering the entire floor. Think of it like the robot is painting the floor and it has to paint the entire floor avoiding all obstacles.

Now my first approach was to put 3 HC-SR ultrasonic sensors on 3 sides and listen to them in a sequence, deciding which path is best and then going there. But this method leaves out quite a lot of floor area uncovered.

So how can I cover the entire floor area here?
 Presently I am working with Arduino UNO and HC-SR04 but wouldn't hesitate to throw my Pi3 or a few more sensors in there...-

Comment: This is more of a robotics question and not really about Arduino,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite a complex thing to achieve. I'll give some suggestions, though this is not something I have attempted (yet).

The main thing to do is divide the room up into a grid. The resolution you choose (X and Y dimensions) depends on how small your robot is, how big the room is, and how much memory your have available (on an Uno that's not much at all).

The second thing you need to do is work out a way of determining exactly where in the room you are. That could be done by trying to get as close to the bottom-left corner as possible before starting to map.

Now you can work from square to square (you could do with some encoders to know how far you have driven, and a magnetometer so you know which direction you are facing) using whatever method you like to decide which way to go, and in each square you look to see which of the squares around you are accessible. From that you can work out which way you can go from that square.

As you go you maintain a map in memory of all the squares you have been to, and the squares that you cannot get to. Note that it may not be enough to say "You can't get to square 4,3" - instead you may to keep a more detailed list (depending on what your obstacles are). "You can't get to square 4,3 from square 4,2, nor 3,3, but you can get to it from square 5,3" for example (e.g., a thin obstacle that only blocks entry to that square from certain sides).

Since your sensors cover longer ranges than just one square (unless you have big squares) you can work out how far away an obstacle is, and mark the square it's in before you even get close to it. The square immediately preceding it on a path between it and you would be the "you can't get there from here" square.

Now you can work out paths and routes to get to the squares you need to so you can cover all the available floor.

Comment: I must say... That was much more complex than I thought it would be.. But I'm gonna give it a shot for sure